# How to take mobile picture, rename it and upload to specified server location

Tags: asp-classic

I am building an asp page styled for mobile phones with the purpose of taking multiple photographs and uploading them to dynamically specified webserver locations using vbsUpload.asp script.

But i can't figure out how change either the filename of the image (it's simply named image.jpg and overwrites itself for every upload) or the server path (the code do not accept added variable to the path string)

Here's the attempt at changing the path:

```
    <%
dim setPath, setBuild, setLoc
setBuild = request("bldnr")
setLoc = request("lokaleid")
'response.Write(setBuild & " " & setLoc) & "<br />"

setPath = server.MapPath("catalogues\"&setBuild)

%>

<!-- #include file="vbsUpload_src/vbsUpload.asp" -->
<form method=post
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action=<%=request.servervariables("script_name")%>>


<label style="height:100px;">
    <input name="image" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" style="display:none;"/>
    <img src="icons/camera.png" height="80">
</label>
<br />

<input type=submit name=submit src="icons/Up.png" style=display:block; font-size:38px;>

</label>

</form>
<%

Dim objUpload, lngLoop

If Request.TotalBytes > 0 Then

    Set objUpload = New vbsUpload

  For lngLoop = 0 to objUpload.Files.Count - 1
    'If accessing this page annonymously,
    'the internet guest account must have
    'write permission to the path below.

    objUpload.Files.Item(lngLoop).Save setPath

    Response.Write "File Uploaded"
    Next

End if
%>
```

Do anyone have an idea here?

Best
Morten

Comment: `action="<%=request.servervariables("script_name")%>?bldnr=<%=setBuild %>&lokaleid=<%=setLoc%>"` ?

Comment: Thanks Flakes - but that changes the path to the page, not the path to objUpload.Files.Item(lngloop).save setPath.

Comment: the objUpload simply cut the variable &setBuild from the setPath string: setPath = server.MapPath("catalogues\"&setBuild)

Comment: Okay. I just wanted to point out that  you could pass the required values as querystring which can be accessed in the upload processing page.

Comment: Right, and good point - i changed method and are now attempting to rename the file after upload using filescripting object move instead.